# Adding Button/Label on Pdf Page using PDFKIT

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios-pdfkit, apple-pdfkit

I am trying to add some interactive buttons on pdf pages. I am showing Pdf file using **Apple PDFKit** and I have implemented **UITapGesture,** so when user tap on screen I show a annotation on it, issue is I want to mark this annotation as number like 1,2,3 etc. and whenever user click on this annotation user should be prompt a message that **do you want to delete it?** and then remove it.
Now,

1. How can I give annotation as numbers 1,2,3 etc.?
2. How can I add action on this same annotations? so that user can delete it on action?

**Note:** If you are unable to understand use case, then just take an example of placing balls of **snooker game** on different places.